# 01: Falha na conexão com TOP

Tags: c#, aplicação-web, conexão

Estou tentando consumir um web service do qual não sou administrador.

Consigo normalmente acessar suas classes, objetos e métodos. O problema é quando eu chamo o método que espera receber requisições, ai encontro o seguinte erro:

```
"01: Falha na conexão com TOP"
```

Já pesquisei por todo canto e não achei resposta, agradeço desde já a quem puder ajudar!

Comment: Seu webservice consome um método de alguma camada implementada por terceiros? ou alguma API do próprio sistema?

Comment: Oi Rafael, o método pertence ao próprio web service. Ele foi gerado através do Protheus

Comment: Ele recebe Requisições SOAP

Comment: Deixa ver se consigo ser mais claro, o webservice é apenas uma camada do projeto, ele provavelmente consome um 'metodo' de uma API do projeto, um repositorio, um metodo da camada de negócios, etc... esse erro está parecendo uma exceção customizada, gerada pela pessoa que implementou o Webservice, existe algum manual de integração ou coisa parecida?